# qlRateHelperEarliestDate and qlRateHelperLatestDate in QuantLib Python

Tags: python, quantlib

I have been using Quantlib Addin, now I am looking for the equivalent function for QuantLib in Python:

=qlRateHelperEarliestDate(RateHelper)

and

=qlRateHelperLatestDate(RateHelper)

Or any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to pen a general answer, since asking a question for each function you'll need won't be very time effective.

The convention for QuantLibXL function names is to map the underlying C++ methods as:

```
ql{class name}{method name}(object, [parameters])
```

so, for instance, the method `yearFraction(Date d1, Date d2)` defined in the class `DayCounter`, which in C++ is called as

```
t = object.yearFraction(d1,d2);
```

in QuantLibXL becomes `qlDayCounterYearFraction(object, d1, d2)`.  (Sometimes the class name is shortened; for instance, the method `discount` in class `YieldTermStructure` is mapped as `qlYieldTSDiscount`).

You can invert the principle to find the C++ (or Python) method from the QuantLibXL function.  The function `qlRateHelperEarliestDate` maps the method `earliestDate` of class `RateHelper`, so `qlRateHelperEarliestDate(rate_helper)` corresponds to `rate_helper.earliestDate()`.

The same goes for `latestDate`, and for most other functions; the first parameter in Excel is the object on which to call the method, and the others are the parameters to pass.